# Feynman parameters in one loop contribution for electron vertex

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

I'm studying one loop contribution for electron vertex function form Peskin and Schroeder's book " An introduction to quantum field theory " Section: 6.3 .. the momentum flow is given as in the following diagram:

[image]

I'm stuck in evaluating the dominator to get Equation (6.44) after Feynman parametrization .. Starting from equ. (6.43) :

$ D= k^2+ 2k . (yq-zp)+ y q^2 + z p^2 -(x+y)m^2 $

after changing the variables $k \to l -(yq-zp) $ I got:

$ D = l^2 - 2 l (yq-zp) + (yq-zp)^2 + 2 l (yq-zp) - 2 (yq-zp)^2  + y q^2 + z p^2 -(x+y)m^2 \\ = l^2 - 2 y z q.p -(x+y)m^2   $

Then I stop here. I think reaching for (6.44) just comes from evaluting $q.p$ depending on the process kinamtics which i can't figure out now , so any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know:

- $p$ is the $4$-momentum of a real incoming particle.
  Therefore it is on the mass-shell,
  $$ p^2 = m^2 . $$
  Note that in this context $q$ is the momentum of a virtual particle, that's why $q^2 \neq 0$ in general.
- From energy-momentum conservation, $p' = p + q$.
  Square both sides to obtain
  $$ m^2 = m^2 + 2pq + q^2 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 2pq = -q^2 $$
- Also I think you cancelled a couple of terms a bit prematurely ;)

I'll write down my calculation starting after the change of variables:
\begin{align}
D &= \ell^2 - (yq - zp)^2 + yq^2 + zp^2 - (x+y) m^2 \\
&= \ell^2 - y^2q^2 +2yz\,pq - z^2 m^2 + yq^2 + zm^2 - (1-z) m^2 \\
&= \ell^2 + \left( -y^2 - yz + y \right) q^2 + \left( -z^2 + z - 1 + z \right) m^2 \\
&= \ell^2 + xy\, q^2 - \left( 1-z \right)^2\, m^2 .
\end{align}

Comment: I hope this follow-up question doesn't come too long after the fact: I certainly agree that in the context of the diagrams P/S are evaluating, p and p' are on-shell. But wouldn't it be more desirable to calculate the vertex function without assuming p and p' are on-shell, so that the result can be slotted into more complicated diagrams? Or are such diagrams very high order in perturbation theory, so that they are not so useful?

Comment: @Zack I just happened to be around, but generally it might make sense to create a new question because I might not always see notifications. Also, I don't quite understand the question. In order to calculate more complicated diagrams, that might be desirable, yes. And there might be research areas where calculating high order contributions is important. However, that is probably not crucial for learning qft.